# The element without default constructor in the custom template container

Tags: c++, containers

I need to create a simple template container, which can store any object of any type and could be used everywhere. So, I did something like this:

```
template <typename Type>
class Container {
public:
    Container() : arraySize(10) { valueWrappers = new Type[arraySize];}

    Container(const Container& other) { /* --- */}
    ~Container() { /* --- */}
    Container& operator=(const Container& other) { /* --- */}

    /* some functions */

private:    
    int arraySize;
    Type* valueWrappers;
};
```

Now I have the problem - when I'm trying to create my container using as template a class without default constructor, the compilation error appears:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int value) :v(value) { }

private:
    int v;
};

int main() {
    Container<MyClass> cont;

    return 0;
}
```

C2512   'MyClass': no appropriate default constructor available

The problem is that I need to initialize the array of "Type" values with something, but I don't no what I need to use. I can't use NULL because, in this case, Container will work only with pointers. So, can somebody give an advice, how am I able to do it? Or, maybe, there is another way to solve this task?

Comment: Why are you writing this type?  Since you're doing a trivial wrapper around a dynamic array, why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Because the task is to create a container without using containers from standard template library

Comment: Can you use `Container<MyClass*>`?  If not, I think you'd have to use placement `new` which comes with quite a few gotchas.

Comment: OK, as far as I said, the task is to create a container "which can store any object of any type", so I need to think out the problem I've described. I need the container which can work either with `Container<MyClass*>` of with `Container<MyClass>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirements, I think you're going to have to use placement `new`.  Since you haven't provided all the relevant code, I'm going to do what I can.

First, you're going to have to allocate raw memory instead of using `new` directly.

```
Container() : arraySize(10) { valueWrappers = reinterpret_cast<Type*>(::operator new(sizeof(Type) * arraySize)); }
```

Now when you put something in your `Container`, you'll have to construct it in place, using something like the following:

```
new (valueWrappers + index) Type(arguments to type);
```

In your destructor, you'll need to explicitly call the destructors on any object that you used placement `new` for.

```
valueWrappers[index]->~Type();
```

Lastly, release the memory using `::operator delete`.

```
::operator delete(valueWrappers);
```

Please bear in mind that this is a very quick and dirty answer, and this code can be hard to debug and maintain.  You're going to have to keep track of what indexes in `valueWrapper` have been initialized and which haven't during cleanup.  If possible, I *highly* recommend using something akin to `std::vector`, which handles all this complexity for you.

Comment: I think that your solution won't work in case some class is inherent from Type. if ther is a driven class it will take more space then sizeof(Type) and then the objects will override one another in this solution.

Comment: @jonathan - Agreed, and the original question uses `Type` as a `template` parameter.  If you needed to store multiple types that have `Type` as a common ancestor, then you'd need to use something akin to `std:::vector<std::unique_ptr<Type>>`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to not allocate the array in the default constructor, but initialise `valueWrappers` to null instead. Another option is to not have a default constructor in your template. Third option is to keep your class as-is and simply document that the template is default constructible only if the type argument is default constructible.

Comment: Well, the second idea is a bit strange, because usually all template containers have default constructor

Comment: @Dmitrii Not all templates need to be usual. `std::array` is another example of a container with no default constructor - well, it does have implicit default constructor if the element type is default constructible.

Comment: I think, in this case, I need a default constructor(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::optional` to defer initialization, which is guaranteed to handle object lifetime correctly.  Letting a default constructed container have 10 elements is also a questionable choice — a `(count)` constructor may be preferable.

```
template <typename Type>
class Container {
    using elem_t = std::optional<Type>;

    std::size_t count{};
    std::unique_ptr<elem_t[]> elems{};
public:
    Container() = default;
    Container(std::size_t cnt)
        : count{cnt}
        , elems{std::make_unique<elem_t[]>(cnt)}
    {
    }
    // for example
    template <typename... Args>
    void construct_at(std::size_t pos, Args&&... args)
    {
        assert(pos < count);
        assert(!elems[pos]);

        elems[pos].emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Note that I used `std::unique_ptr` to simplify memory management; a pointer will also be OK, though apparently more error-prone.  Now you can traverse the container and construct the elements:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int value) :v(value) { }
private:
    int v;
};

int main()
{
    Container<MyClass> cont(10);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cont.construct_at(i, /* argument */);
    }
}
```